# Passing data from nodejs/express to frontend js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the below codes, I am trying to access `data` sent from my backend server in my frontend js. How can I do that?

**Express**

```
...
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {data} );
});
...
```

**home.ejs**

```
...
<script src="frontend.js"></script>
...
```

**frontend.js**

```
var data = <%=data%>; // this didnt work...
```

Comment: take a look at this [accessing passed ejs variable in javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539106/accessing-passed-ejs-variable-in-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

You could directly inject the data variable into javascript on the page.

```
<% if (data) { %>
     <h2>I have data</h2>
     <script>
        var data = <%= data %>            
     </script>
<% } %>
```

Another option might be to make an AJAX call back to the server once the page has already loaded, return the data

Comment: you may refer this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser